# Swap 2 column stacking order at small scrn- Bootstrap push pull class or float fix?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

No matter what I do I can't get the right column to push over and stack first at 100% width/small scrns. I tried col-xs-pull/push-12 or col-xs-pull/push-0. I also tried messing around with the div floats, to no avail.

Am I missing something obvious, or do I need to start a Phase 2 of this conundrum?

```
<div class="row>
<div id="main" class= "col-xs-12 col-xs-pull-? col-sm-8"></div>
<div id="r-column" class="col-xs-12 col-xs-push-? col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

If you go with a "mobile first" approach, you put the r-column first in your marking and then use push/pull accordingly

```
<div class="row">
 <div id="r-column" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-push-8 col-sm-4">right</div>
 <div id="main" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-pull-4 col-sm-8">main</div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/121630

Comment: Thank you that did the trick. I did have to add an additional MQ for the the push/pull classes per my design, as well.

Comment: Yes, this is the appropriate way to do it. Looks like you will have to rearrange code, but it is actually a lot simpler than hacking a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

i use this in mobile - swap col

```
/* SET order of DIV */
@media only screen and (max-width:991px) {
    .order {
        display:-webkit-flex;
        display:flex;       
        flex-direction:column;
        -webkit-flex-direction:column;
    }
    .order .ord1 {
        order:1;-webkit-order:1;

    }
    .order .ord2 {
        order:2;-webkit-order:2;
    }
    .order .ord3 {
        order:3;-webkit-order:3;
   }
    .order .ord4 {
        order:4;-webkit-order:5;
    }
}
```

.

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row order">
        <div class="ord2 col-xs-12 col-md-3">Last</div>
        <div class="ord1 col-xs-12 col-md-3">First</div>
    </div>
</div>
```